# Geoserver 2.19.0-MapML

Tags: plugins, geoserver

If I´m using the standard admin account, can I still install the MapML plugin and make it work?

I´ve downloaded the right version of the plugin and put the Jar-files in the lib folder, restarted Geoserver but the plugin does not show. No more options from MapML, and it´s not there when looking at the Layer Preview table.

Any idea of what´s missing?

//Bjorn

Comment: Where did you download the extension from? I've just tried it locally and it works

Comment: Downloaded from geoserver. Now I realized that I did put the Jar-files in the wrong Lib-folder. I found another one in Webapps-Geoserver-WEB-INF-Lib, then it works fine.